# Service Fabric Restart Application

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell

I have a service fabric app that reads from KeyVault on startup. When we change the KeyVault value we have to restart the nodes for it to read the new value. This causes the other applications on the same node to go down.

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to restart the service fabric application I have got the following script working on a 1 node cluster however it does not work on multiple node cluster.

```
Restart-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage -ApplicationName $appName -CommandCompletionMode Verify -ServiceName $ServiceName -TimeoutSec 8000
```

When I have a multiple node cluster this does not work. I can't figure out why it will not work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As a note, this is not the recommended way to handle key rotations. I'll take this up in the github issue you opened regarding the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum amount of parameters that I made this powershell command work are:

`-ApplicationName`
`-NodeName`
`-ServiceManifestName`
`-CodePackageName`
`-ServicePackageActivationId`

Like this:
`Restart-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage -ApplicationName fabric:/App -NodeName "Node01" -ServiceManifestName "ServicePkg" -CodePackageName "Code" -ServicePackageActivationId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Using this command I sometimes get weird error `Did not find deployed code package for fabric:/App:Code on node Node01` but at least every time service gets restarted. I've played with other parameters combinations but with no luck. It seems above parameters are must.

Writing generic powershell script which restart specific service (and only this service) on all nodes, I would've firstly take all node names running `Get-ServiceFabricNode` and then iterating on these names run `Get-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage -NodeName Node01 -ApplicationName fabric:/App -ServiceManifestName ServicePkg` in order to take `ServicePackageActivationId` which is the only parameter that is dynamic. And finally with `ServicePackageActivationId` run `Restart-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage`

Comment: So why is there an error if the service gets restarted?

Comment: The error "Did not find deployed code package for fabric:/App:Code on node Node01 " is a transient race condition. The command is attempting to verify that the package comes back, but at the time it makes the internal check the actual service hasn't restarted yet. This is benign/expected.

Comment: Having the same issue and then ran it again and it worked! dodgy stuff

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with only `ApplicationName` and `Servicename` and it worked !

> Restart-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage -ApplicationName app_name -ServiceName service_name